# PICT: Incorrect numeric value

Tags: testing

I use pict.exe from Microsoft for pairwise testing. I have following input file content:

```
SomeString: Value1, Value2
SomeFloat: 0.00, 50.00, 100.00

IF [SomeString] = Value1 THEN [SomeFloat] = 0.00;
```

But when I am running pict.exe with this file, I get error:

```
Input Error: Incorrect numeric value: IF [SomeString] = Value1 THEN [SomeFloat] = 0.00;
```

I've tried to use different values (integers), but problem wasn't solved. I also read pict docs and issues in their repo, but didn't find anything relative to my problem.

Comment: Turned out that I forgot "" for the SomeString value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using conditions, you should wrap string values into "". After that the problem had gone.

Instead of

```
IF [SomeString] = Value1 THEN [SomeFloat] = 0.00;
```

you should write

```
IF [SomeString] = "Value1" THEN [SomeFloat] = 0.00;
```